# Finding node module from different directory?

Tags: node.js

Always feel stupid asking here because people are always confused with my questions, or I have a dumb problem, but, I'm working on a program in node.js and the text editor I'm using (NP++) doesn't seem to like to save files in the system32 directoy, (The directory where my modules are), and that is where my script is as well. (So I have .../.../node_modules/(modules) and .../.../node_modules/script.js) this becomes a pain when I want to edit the script, I have to clone the script to my desktop, then edit it, then overwrite the one in the node_modules directory. I tried saving the script to my desktop and running it, but it just gives me an error of module not found. (In my script I have the modules as `var example = require('example.js')`) Is there any way I can get it to get the modules from the node_modules directory, while keeping the script file somewhere easily accessible and editable? (i.e desktop?) (Sorry if this is confusing, not the best at these kind of things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that this is what's happening because I haven't used npm on Windows, but it sounds to me like you're installing your dependencies **globally** using `npm -g`. The more proper way to use Node is to install your dependencies **locally**, using `npm` without the `-g` flag. That way your dependencies get installed in your current working directory.

For example, let's say you've saved your project in a directory on your Desktop, and your script uses `require("lodash")`. If you `cd` to your directory and run `npm install lodash`, then the `lodash` module will be available to your script.

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm!